# Web Design: Dynamic Maps

Tags: php, javascript, html, web, maps

I'm fairly new to web design and I would really like to know how to create a dynamic map from scratch. Here is the idea. The website takes a poll from users (from let's say the US). I want to update a map of the US and darken the regions of the map as more people from that location participates (they enter their location). How would I do this? What are some resources to get started with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do this with googlemap api Heatmaps.
Sample https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

Please refer https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers for more details